# AMD Catalyst installation woes on Slackware

Tags: slackware, amd-graphics

I'm trying to get my ATI graphics driver installed on my fresh Slackware OS (Zenwalk). I'm coming from Ubuntu 14.04-14.10, so I know there's a whole lot I don't understand just yet.

**I download the .zip archive from [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64), then `unzip` it to extract the .run file.**

```
sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg
```

**generates the following output:**

```
Created directory fglrx-install.hu4jBU
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-8.97.100.7.........
=====================================================================
 AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================
Generating package: Slackware/Slackware

ATI SlackBuild 
-------------------------------------------- 
by: Emanuele Tomasi <tomasi@cli.di.unipi.it> 

AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
kernel includes at /usr/src/linux/include not found or incomplete
file: /usr/src/linux/include/linux/version.h
ERROR: I didn't make module
Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.hu4jBU
```

Using the command `./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run` runs the GUI setup, but results in the same error. I'm not sure what to make of this error, or what steps I should be taking. Any assistance is appreciated.

If it matters, `uname -r` = **3.14.5**

Comment: Not what you want to hear, but I had a disastrous time with that installer too. I had better luck with the system standard fglrx driver. But as to your error, it looks like you need to install the headers package for your kernel. I eventually went to nvidia graphics and haven't had a problem with them of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this by impatiently reformatting everything and freshly installing Ubuntu 14.04 again. Now everything works as it should.

Comment: With Ubuntu's driver, or with Catalyst? I don't think I'd ever touch the latter ever again, but if you got it to work ...

Comment: @rayandrews I'm just running with whatever shipped in Ubuntu. It worked fine before, it seems to be working fine now. I love my crusty old Sapphire ATI, I just want to know that I'm actually utilizing it to its full potential. And yeah, I seem to see less grief coming from the Nvidia side of things, but I built this dinosaur from the ground up with an AMD backbone. Next time around perhaps...

Comment: Ok. Be safe and stay away from that Catalyst disaster ;-)